# No encuentro los errores de este código

Tags: javascript, html

Muy buenas tardes,

Estoy recién aprendiendo a programar con HTML y Javascript y no sé muy bien cuáles son los errores de este pequeño código. Ya había escrito antes en este foro para pedir consejo sobre este mismo código, pero ahora que lo estoy ampliando no me funciona. Agradecería mucho si alguien puede chivarme alguno de los errores o al menos darme alguna pista:)

Muchas gracias.

```js
class Mates {
  static grados(radianes) {
    return (radianes * 180 / Math.PI) * Math.PI;
  }
  static radianessinpi(radianessinpivalor) {
    return (radianessinpivalor * 180 / Math.PI);
  }
  static radianes(grados) {
    return (grados * Math.PI / 180) / Math.PI;
  }
}

function formulario_calculadora() {
  const radianes = document.f1.radianes.value;
  const radianessinpi = document.f1.radianessinpi.value;
  const grados = document.f1.grados.value;
  if (grados == '') {
    resultado = Mates.grados(radianes);
    document.f1.radianes.value = null;
    document.f1.resrad.value = radianes;
    document.f1.resgrad.value = resultado;
    document.f1.resgradms.value = Math.floor(resultado);
    document.f1.resgmins.value = Math.floor(parseInt(resultado)*60);
    document.f1.resgmseg.value = parseInt(parseInt(resultado)*60);
  } else if (radianessinpi = '') {
    resultado = Mates.radianessinpi(radianessinpivalor);
    document.f1.radianessinpi.value = null;
    document.f1.resrad.value = resultado;
    document.f1.resgrad.value = grados(resultado);
    document.f1.resgradms.value = Math.floor(grados(resultado));
    document.f1.resgmins.value = Math.floor(parseInt(grados(resultado))*60);
    document.f1.resgmseg.value = parseInt(parseInt(grados(resultado))*60);
  } else {
    resultado = Mates.radianes(grados);
    document.f1.grados.value = null;
    document.f1.resgrad.value = grados;
    document.f1.resrad.value = resultado;
    document.f1.resgradms.value = Math.floor(grados);
    document.f1.resgmins.value = Math.floor(parseInt(grados)*60);
    document.f1.resgmseg.value = parseInt(parseInt(grados)*60);
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Codigo de ejemplo</title>
<form name="f1">
  Grados: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="grados"> º <br>
  Radianes: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="radianes"> π rad <br>
  Radianes sin π: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="radianessinpi"> rad <br><br>
  <input onclick="formulario_calculadora()" type="button" value="Convertir"><br><br>
  Resultado grados decimales: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="resgrad"> º <br>
  Resultado grados-minutos-segundos: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="resgradms"> º
  <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="resgmins"> ' <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="resgmseg"> ''<br>
  Resultado radianes: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="resrad"> π rad<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa [ask]. En concreto, explica qué fallo has detectado (no se ejecuta, resultado incorrecto...)

Comment: Sí, básicamente si pulsas el botón de ejecución en la mayoría de casos no funciona, pero en radianes sí. Sin embargo el resultado es incorrecto:)

Comment: Una vez más: recordá que [es.so] no es un servicio de depuración de código, y leé [ask]. Aparte de ello, en las otras preguntas estás dejando respuestas sin aceptar, y estás omitiendo los comentarios que los demás usuarios te están dejando en las preguntas. _Este no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Errores de código tienes algunos_
El segundo `if` tienes

```
...
  } else if(radianessinpi = '')
```

Ese signo `=` es de asignación no de comparación, debes usar `==` o `===`
Después de `if(radianessinpi == '')` usas `radianesinpivalor`, pero esa variable no existe.

Usas grados que no existe como función, sino como método de la clase Mate. Debieras usar `Mates.grados()`
En cuanto a la lógica no te digo nada, porque no me he puesto a destriparla.